# Not able to get/read tooltip text in Coded UI c#

Tags: c#, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I am doing coded ui for wpf and web application where i have to read tool tip text on mouse over of some element but not getting actual text of tool tip. Please help me-- i have used below code:

```
  WinControls.WinControl = New WinControls.WinWindow
            win.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "Open")
            win.SetFocus()
           WinControls.WinButton = New WinControls.WinButton(win)
            btn.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "My Recent Documents")
             WinControls.WinToolTip = New WinControls.WinToolTip(win)
            Mouse.Hover(btn)
            tip.SearchProperties.Add("ClassName", "tooltip")
            Dim nme = tip.Name
```

Comment: From my experience tool tips are hard to catch especially in win forms.. if your control has a DisplayText or HelpText property it might give you the value you need

Comment: Have you simply tried `btn.ToolTipText` (maybe after a small wait)? That should work, you don' need a WinToolTip instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the tooltip from btn.ToolTipText.

```
       WinControls.WinControl = New WinControls.WinWindow
        win.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "Open")
        win.SetFocus()
       WinControls.WinButton = New WinControls.WinButton(win)
        btn.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "My Recent Documents")
         WinControls.WinToolTip = New WinControls.WinToolTip(win)
        Mouse.Hover(btn)
        Trace.WriteLin(btn.ToolTipText)
```